# Remove the max value splitLine on Y axis

Tags: charts, svelte, echarts, apache-echarts

I've been trying to hide the max value splitLine on Y axis. It is marked in the image below:

[image: Chart with the problematic splitLine]

What I am trying to achieve is to have the max value of Y axis be 30% larger than the max value of the actual data I get but without the splitLine showing for that max value. That way the Y axis is longer and it looks nicer. Without adding the max option the Y axis stops at the max value of the data array.

Chart settings:

```js
export const chartConfig = {
  max: (value: { max: number; min: number }) => value.max * 1.3,
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ["Q1 '24", "Q2 '24", "Q3 '24", "Q4 '24"],
    axisTick: {
      show: false,
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    axisLine: {
      show: true,
    },
    axisLabel: {
      showMaxLabel: false,
    },

    name: 'Y axis',
    nameGap: 50,
    nameLocation: 'middle',
    nameTextStyle: {
      fontSize: 14,
    },
  },
  legend: {
    type: 'plain',
    bottom: '2%',
    left: '10%',
  },
  tooltip: {
    show: true,
  },
  grid: { left: '10%' },
  series: [
    {
      data: [13000],
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'a',
      name: 'First value',
      itemStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(69, 101, 76)',
      },
    },
    {
      data: [8000],
      type: 'bar',
      stack: 'a',
      name: 'Second value',
      itemStyle: {
        color: 'rgb(245, 218, 102)',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I've tried playing with the `interval` and `splitNumber` settings to no avail. Went through anything related to ticks, intervals, splitLines and Y axis in the docs: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: Does anything prevent you from using [yAxis max](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.max)? `max: value => value.max * 1.3`

Comment: @MatthiasMertens Nothing other than my attention span and IQ. I have changed it to `max: value => value.max * 1.3` but as expected the issue still persists. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Which issue persists? I dont think it is possible to remove the max splitLine but setting yAxis max should extend the yAxis to the specified value.

Comment: I am probably misunderstanding you but it was never the issue that my yAxis was not extended to the specified value. I managed to do it as you can see on the screen capture. The only reason why I have posted this question is because I need help finding a way to get rid of that splitLine. 
I thought of trying to add one more Y axis that would be invisible and set max data to it maybe with all the settings set to "show: false" but I never got to test it yet. If I manage to find a workaround I will definitely update my question and post it. 
Either way, thanks for the input

Comment: Then I misunderstood this "In case it isn't possible, what I am trying to achieve is to have the max value of Y axis be 30% larger than the max value of the actual data I get" part

Comment: I did not explain it well, you understood it well for how it was written. I have edited the text for better clarity to avoid any potential confusion in the future.